# Email selection from Excel using Outlook

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

In Excel I have a contact list, e.g.:

```
  A                   B
1 Bob Marley          bob.marley@hotmail.com
2 Michael Jackson     michael.jackson@outlook.com
3 Freddie Mercury     freddie.mercury@gmail.com
```

Is there some VBA code that will copy the email addresses (`B1:B3`) and open a new email item in Outlook and paste the email addresses into the 'To' section in the email?

I've looked at the following web references but they don't seem to work:

http://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-a-new-message-using-vba/

[Open new message in Outlook by Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747284/open-new-message-in-outlook-by-excel-vba)

[VBA Outlook Mail .display, recording when/if sent manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533066/vba-outlook-mail-display-recording-when-if-sent-manually)

Answer (score 0):

That first reference very nearly does it for you. Just adjust the hard coded 'to' value as the cell value. Put the thing in a loop if you want all three addresses.

```
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With objMsg
  .To = Range("B2").Value
  .Subject = "This is the subject"

  .Display
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

This is tested on my comp

```
Sub practisemail()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

     With objMail
      .To = Range("B2").Value
      .Subject = "This is the subject"
      .Display
    End With

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried your code and I get the error: "Array Lower Bound must be Zero", and it says the problem is the line '.To = Range("B2").Value`

Can you please help?

Comment: It's also worth noting that I want to send an email to all of the email addresses and not just one of them

Comment: get one working then we can worry about sending it to all.

Comment: Yes that works! That's got one recipient in the 'To' section, how would I go about getting the others in there? Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you want them in the same email or different emails? @Grade Lol!

Comment: All in the same email, so say one email that contains the three recipients

Comment: Try `.To = Range("B1").Value & ";" & Range("B2").Value & ";" & Range("B3").Value`

Comment: I don't always know what the cell range would be though, i.e. someone might add an email address onto the line, would `Range("B1:B45")` work?